# Website crashing both on mobile Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

Is there anyway to troubleshoot on mobile to know what's causing this. The website has a lot of images, is a little bit heavy but I'm not sure if that justifies the fact that it always crashes.
I'm using an Iphone 4s btw.. Thanks

Comment: Mobile browsers (at least older ones) tend to have memory constraints at about the 8-10MB range. If you're well below this, then it is likely a code issue as opposed to a memory issue.

Comment: And how can I know which line of code is causing this ? @Quantastical

Comment: Debug your code. One way would be to comment out blocks of code and reintegrate small sections to see what block is causing problems. Or, since you're using Chrome, add a `debugger;` line to your JavaScript and step through to see what's going on.

Comment: I have a iphone 4, and the only page that did crash was Espacos. Maybe you could start by inspecting this page. It crashed, but did display the content of the page.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to optimize your images for the web. This would help with the loading speed. You have 96dpi images. Maybe bring them down to 72 dpi and make them 70 quality, which would be sufficient. You could resize the header images from 2500 to 1920 width also. Just a suggestion

Comment: @IndieRok they are already 72dpi images. Where did you saw 96dpi images? Also, they were all saved for web with 70quality. Also, how could I know whats causing this problems if it's only on mobile ?

Comment: @Quantastical how can I do that if the problem only happens on mobile ?

Comment: You can do remote debugging for iOS Safari by connecting your device to your computer and enabling Developer Tools in desktop Safari. Then, on the device go to Settings, Advanced, and activate the Web Inspector. Then, in the Developer menu on desktop, you will have the option of inspecting your mobile device's browser. Don't think that'll work with Chrome, but maybe resolving for Safari will resolve for Chrome.

Comment: @FranciscoCouto: I downloaded "fundoquartos.jpg" and right-clicked/properties and that's where I saw the 96dpi setting.  I really like the site by the way. That hidden menu at the top is really nice. Good job

Comment: @Quantastical, I didn't know you could debug on a MAC like that by connecting a device. Good to know, thanks!

Comment: @IndieRok Weird, I just downloaded the image through the website and it shows 96dpi on properties. But when I open on photoshop, it shows 72. Now I'm not even sure if I'm looking to the right thing. u.u  
I'm glad you liked the website. Thank you